# Recursive search on dict and return path

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

```
data = {
   "A_level_1":{
      "A_level_2":{
         "A_level_3":{
            "A_level_4":"some value"
         }
      },
      "B_level_2":{
         "B_level_3":{
            "B_level_4":{
               "B_level_5":"some value"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

unfortunately i have not a big progress:

```
def find(search_dict, path):
   for key, value in search_dict.items():
      if isinstance(value, dict):
         find(value, key+".")
```

Can you please help me to implement function to find key and build path of keys.
Method get a dictionary and key to find. Expected result path of nested keys separated by dot:

- `find(data,"A_level_3")`: `A_level_1.A_level_2.A_level_3`
- `find(data,"B_level_3")`: `A_level_1.B_level_2.B_level_3`
- `find(data,"B_level_5")`: `A_level_1.B_level_2.B_level_3.B_level_4.B_level_5`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
def find(search_dict, target_key, path=""):
    for key, value in search_dict.items():
        new_path = f"{path}{key}."

        if key == target_key:
            return new_path[:-1]

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            nested_result = find(value, target_key, new_path)
            if nested_result is not None:
                return nested_result

    return None
```

but I'm using `isintance` that I don't like. Anyway there is probably an `itertools` method that do this faster.

Comment: What's not to like about `isinstance`? And which `itertools` method are you talking about?

Comment: @Stef read this years ago [canonical.org](http://canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/). For the `itertools`, read my statement, never said it exists.

Comment: Fair enough about `isinstance`. An alternative to `if isinstance(value, dict):` could be: `try; for k,v in value.items(): code_for_dict(); except AttributeError: code_for_not_dict`

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what is missing from your code:

- Your function is missing a `search_key` argument, to remember what key you're searching for;
- You only search the key in values; but it could be in keys, so you need a separate if/elif branch for that;
- When you make a recursive call, you need to capture the return value of the recursive call in a variable, and check whether or not you've found your search key in this recursive call;
- If you never find the search key, then you should return `None` to indicate that the search key wasn't found.

```py
def find(search_dict, search_key, path=''):
   path = path + '.' if path != '' else path
   for key, value in search_dict.items():
      if key == search_key:
          return path + key
      elif value == search_key:
          return ''.join((path, key, '.', value))
      elif isinstance(value, dict):
         subresult = find(value, search_key, path + key)
         if subresult is not None:
             return subresult
   return None

>>> find(data, "A_level_3")
'A_level_1.A_level_2.A_level_3'
>>> find(data, "B_level_5")
'A_level_1.B_level_2.B_level_3.B_level_4.B_level_5'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for a matching key somehow (which your function doesn't do):

```
def find(search_dict,search_key):
    if not isinstance(search_dict,dict):  # can't dig any deeper
        return 
    elif search_key in search_dict:       # found the search_key
        return search_key
    for key,value in search_dict.items(): # drill down dictionary
        path = find(value,search_key)
        if path: return key+"."+path      # bring back full path
```

output:

```
print(find(data,"A_level_3"))
A_level_1.A_level_2.A_level_3

print(find(data,"B_level_3"))
A_level_1.B_level_2.B_level_3

print(find(data,"B_level_5"))
A_level_1.B_level_2.B_level_3.B_level_4.B_level_5
```